# How can I call files without listing the entire path?

Tags: java

I am building an authentication system. I have a group of files that are in the src file of the program. I need to call those files to check against and also display. My program is currently working perfectly and I'm calling them like this:

```
    File credFile = new File("C:\\Users\\gsiek\\Documents\\Final Project\\Authentication System\\src\\authentication\\system\\credentials.txt");
    File zkFile = new File("C:\\Users\\gsiek\\Documents\\Final Project\\Authentication System\\src\\authentication\\system\\zookeeper.txt");
    File vetFile = new File("C:\\Users\\gsiek\\Documents\\Final Project\\Authentication System\\src\\authentication\\system\\veterinarian.txt");
    File adminFile = new File("C:\\Users\\gsiek\\Documents\\Final Project\\Authentication System\\src\\authentication\\system\\admin.txt");
```

The problem I have is that I'm afraid when I submit this project for grading, the program won't work because I have the entire path for my computer. How can I change this so that I can call the file without listing the entire path that is specific to my computer?

Comment: By letting the user of your program specify where the file are located on his. Using, for example, an argument, or a System property, or a configuration file, or whatever. Or by choosing a location that all computers have, like the user's directory, which is available in a standard System property.

Comment: Your fear is well-founded, this will not work. Are the files part of your source code (i.e. they don't change)? If yes, you should put them as resources.

Comment: How do you have to submit your project? As a .jar file, separate source files with some build system (ie. Maven, gradle, ant) or something else?